# TListBox - Selected Item Scroll Speed

Tags: delphi, listbox, scroll

I need to change the speed that a list box is scrolled when an item is selected (holding left mouse button down) and the mouse is moved outside of the list box. To duplicate the behavior do the following:

1. Drop a list box on the form (+- 250 x 200 odd). Don't make it too big otherwise the scroll bar won't be visible at the bottom.
2. Set the number of columns to 3.
3. Add the following code to the FormCreate:

   ```
   var
     I: Integer;
   begin
     for I := 0 to 200 do
       ListBox1.Items.Add('Item '+IntToStr(I));
   end;
   ```
4. Run the application and make sure that a scroll bar at the bottom is visible. Now click and hold down the left mouse button on any of the items in the list. Move the mouse and the selected item will change depending on which item is under the mouse cursor. The problem is that the list box will scroll very quickly when the mouse moves outside of the listbox which is necessary in my case to select items that are hidden. I am trying to slow down this scroll speed.

I understand that this is not the normal usage of a list box and that the behavior might not exactly fit into the standard UI guidelines. It's needed for a very specific purpose, the problem is that the scroll speed makes it very awkward for users.

I have put something together using drag and drop and a timer but that's not ideal as the "hit" area around the control is a little bit small. It would be nice if there was an out of the box way to do it.

Comment: I would learn the users to scroll the mouse wheel. It has a nice effect on Windows 7 :)

Comment: Unfortunately the scroll wheel doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: Am I missing something here ? I thought your aim is to get to an item which is outside the client rectangle view. That's where you can scroll by the wheel...

Comment: When I stop moving the mouse, scrolling stops here. When moved again without releasing the button, it starts scrolling again. So looks like it's kind of possible to control scrolling. Anyway, you won't find anything out of the box.

Comment: *"scroll bar at the bottom"* -> "at the right"?

Comment: @TLama Yes, that is the required behavior. The problem is that the list box is only shown when the mouse is already clicked and hidden when they release the mouse button. The mouse wheel doesn't work in that situation.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, that is correct. The scroll bar is on the bottom. I was hoping that there was a message I could post to the control or some other way of controlling the automatic scroll speed. I don't mind getting my hands dirty I just couldn't find anything on list boxes that would let me control this. Even ignoring Delphi.

Comment: A list box that only shows when the mouse is down. That sounds weird. What led you there?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's for clicking on the axis of a chart to select which parameter should be show on the chart. Click and hold on the parameter and the listbox is brought to the front with all of the available parameters. The user can then select the parameter that they would like displayed by moving the mouse over the parameter they would like and then releasing. It's an existing system so the behavior is already something that the users are comfortable with.

Comment: That sounds like a really hard to use interface. Asking the user to perform a drag like action that does not drag seems like a bad idea to me. I would not do it this way. You are denying the ability to wheel scroll or even use normal scroll bars, or type to select, or use page up/down. Not ideal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As I said, it's an existing system and the UI style is already something that the users are comfortable with. In most cases they are selecting from between 5 and 10 items so no scroll bar is even shown. It's only the odd situation where the user has more than 30 parameters where the scroll bar is visible. The problem is that in this situation it becomes awkward because the scroll speed is very high.

Comment: The system use a timer for scrolling, I mean `WM_TIMER`. Maybe you can eat one third of them, or the like... BTW, I see a vertical scrollbar that's on the right, I think I don't even understand why do you see one at the bottom.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thanks, I will investigate the timer. The reason for the scroll bar at the bottom is that columns is 3. In your case, the columns is probably still set to 0.

Comment: @Gray - I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that your users have learnt to use your UI doesn't mean it is a good design. That you are asking this question should tell you that. What I see here is a weak piece of UI that makes it difficult to to select items. Perhaps the weakness was less apparent when there were only a small number of items. It seems that the large number of items has accentuated the root problem.

Comment: @Gray - Doesn't look like it will help. Even if you kill all timer messages, it scrolls all the same. Wonder what does it do with it...

Comment: @Sertac *When I stop moving the mouse, scrolling stops here. When moved again without releasing the button, it starts scrolling again.* Sounds more like it is the processing of an input message that provokes selection re-think rather than timer.

Comment: @David - Looks like it indeed, yes. I used some debug output hoping to get a feel of what the timer messages might be serving. They come the most frequent when I stop moving the mouse (while drag-scrolling) - when there's no scrolling at all. I'm really at a loss about the reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is awkward at the very least. However it's the only thing I can think of. Demonstrated using an interposer, but you can use an ApplicationEvents component or subclass any other way you like.

```
type
  TListBox = class(stdctrls.TListBox)
  protected
    procedure WMMouseMove(var Message: TWMMouseMove); message WM_MOUSEMOVE;
  end;

procedure TListBox.WMMouseMove(var Message: TWMMouseMove);
begin
  if GetCapture = Handle then
    Sleep(250);
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: I can definitely work with this as a starting point. Is it bad practice to eat the mouse move messages? So if I have determined that it's not time to scroll again and this message will result in a scroll then can I eat it rather than do something like a sleep?

Comment: @Gray - Why, no. Eating would be definitely better than waiting.

Comment: @Gray It amazes me that you prefer this to scroll bars, keyboard nav. etc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's not that I prefer it. I have recently joined the company. The software is 10+ years old. Over that time people have become used to the software and how it works. It wouldn't be difficult to move the logic onto a popup form and it is probably something that will be done in the future. At the same time it would probably make sense to add filtering or another feature to justify the change in the clients eyes. For now, a timer and msg handler is simpler, needs less testing and doesn't require any "learning" for customers. It just makes more sense for now (time/reward).